# I don't show the image in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter

The image doesn't show in Tkinter. The same code work in a new window, but in my class it does not. What could be the problem ?

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk


class InterfaceApp(root):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        root.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):
        frPic = Tkinter.Frame(bg='', colormap='new')
        im = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="tr.gif")
        imLabel = Tkinter.Label(frPic, image=im)
        frPic.grid(row = 4, columnspan = 10, sticky='EW')
        imLabel.grid(row=3,column=30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InterfaceApp(None)
    app.title("P")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep a reference to `tr.gif` . This means you need to add this line:

```
imLabel.image = im
```

After these 2 lines:

```
im = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="tr.gif")
imLabel = Tkinter.Label(frPic, image=im)
```

Other notes:

- Run import Tkinter as Tk instead of what you have done
- Fix this: `root = Tkinter.Tk()` (add parentheses)
- Change `app = InterfaceApp(None)` to `app = InterfaceApp(root)`
- Remove away `app.title("P")` and write inside `__init__()` this `self.parent.title("P")`
- Change `app.mainloop()` to `root.mainloop()`

Comment: i have fixed it. 
`import Tkinter as Tk` fixed, <br/>
`root = Tk.Tk()` fixed
`class InterfaceApp():` fixed
 `root.__init__(self,parent)` removed.
`root.title("P")` fixed
`app = InterfaceApp(root)` fixed
 `root.mainloop()` fixed