# I am using PhotoImage in python to make a image, but it cannot find a image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, photoimage

I am creating a python board game, but i cant even put my board on my GUI!
I am using:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
panel = Label(root, image = "board.gif")
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

But it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GAMEKNIGHT7/Desktop/genius hour/chineseCheckersAI(genius hour).py", line 3, in <module>
    label = Label(image="board.gif")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "board.gif" doesn't exist
```

What happened? How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't show the image in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370560/i-dont-show-the-image-in-tkinter)

Comment: @snipsnipsnip That is not a good duplicate. The OPs problem is more related to missing PhotoImage all-together rather than simple not saving a reference to the image.

Comment: You're right. I retracted the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the PhotoImage class:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file="board.gif")
panel = Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
root.mainloop()
```